# JMeter: What is a good test structure for load testing REST APIs?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am load testing (baseline, capacity, longevity) a bunch of APIs (eg. user service, player service, etc) using JMeter. Each of these services have several endpoints (eg. create, update, delete, etc). I am trying to figure out a good way to organize my test plans in JMeter so that I can load test all of these services.

1) Is it a good idea to create a separate JMeter Test Plan (jmx) for each of the APIs rather than creating one JMeter test plan and adding thread groups like "Thread Group for User Service", "Thread Group for Player Service", etc? I was thinking about adding one test plan per API, and then adding several Thread Groups for different types of load testing (baseline, capacity, longevity, etc).

2) When JMeter calculates the Sample Time (Response Time), does it also include the time taken by the BeanShell Processors?

3) Is it a good idea to put a Listener inside of each Simple Controller? I am using JMeter Plugins for reporting. I wanted to view the reports for each endpoint.

Answers to any or all of the questions would be much appreciated :)

I am using a structure like below for creating a test plan in JMeter.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) I like a test plan to look like a test suite.  JMeter has several ways of separating components and test requirements, so it can be hard to set a rule.  One test plan is likely to be more efficient than several, and can be configured to satisfy most requirements. I find there can be alot of repetition between plans, which often means maintaining the same code in different places.  Better to use modules and includes on the same plan to reduce code duplication, but includes are equivalent and can be used with test fragments to reduce duplication.

Threadgroups are best used as user groups, but can be used to separate tests any way you please.  Consider the scaling you need for different pages/sites. ie User/Administrator tests can be done in different Thread Groups, so you can simulate say 50 users and 2 admins testing concurrently. Or you may distinguish front-end/back-end or even pages/sites.

2) It does not include beanshell pre- and post-processing times. (But if you use a beanshell sampler, it depends on the code)

3) listeners are expensive, so fewer is better.  To separate the results, you can give each sampler a different title, and the listeners/graphs can then group these as required.  You can include timestamps or indexes as part of your sampler title using variables, properties and ${__javaScript}, etc.  This will cause more or less grouping depending on the implementation you choose.